# Python: How do I programmatically clear the viewer in FreeCAD?

Tags: python, freecad

I can use a Python script to create and show a part in FreeCAD like this:

```
Part.show(myPart)
```

But if I run the script again, it overlays a second copy of myPart on top of the original.  How can the Python script clear the viewer before it starts drawing?  I can manually use the FreeCAD menu to "Select All" and then "Delete", but how can I automate that to speed up my workflow?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the solution I came up with:

```
def clearAll():
    doc = FreeCAD.ActiveDocument
    for obj in doc.Objects:
        doc.removeObject(obj.Label)
```

Comment: You should think about making this the accepted answer if nobody has anything else to add!

Comment: You may add `if doc is None: return` before the loop, to handle no document open at all.

Comment: In the current FreeCAD version I think one should reference the object Name instead of the object label: doc.removeObject(obj.Name)